# False result about linear programming problem from pulp to gurobipy

Tags: python, math, optimization, linear-programming, pulp

This is my first time ask question on Stack Overflow.
Recently I try to convert gurobipy code to pulp and meet some problem.
Data resource:

- A list of employees with their available work hours, and hourly salaries:
  [image]
- A prescibed minimum number of staff needed to be at work at a given hour (fewer staff are needed at night, more staff are needed during peak hours)
  [image]
  (ref: https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2016/01/06/generating-an-optimal-employee-work-schedule-using-integer-linear-programming/)

Goal:

- Minimize the total daily wages the employer must pay out.

Constraints:

- At any given hour, you must meet the minimum staffing requirement.
- An employee can only work one shift a day.
- An employee must work within his available hours.
- If an employee is called for duty, they must work at least a specified minimum number of hours, and no more than a specified maximum number of hours

Original gurobipy Code:

```
import gurobipy
# Create Data
EMPLOYEE, MIN, MAX, COST, START, END = gurobipy.multidict({
    "SMITH"   : [6, 8, 30, 6, 20], "JOHNSON": [6, 8, 50, 0, 24], 'WILLIAMS': [6, 8, 30, 0, 24],
    'JONES'   : [6, 8, 30, 0, 24], 'BROWN': [6, 8, 40, 0, 24], 'DAVIS': [6, 8, 50, 0, 24],
    'MILLER'  : [6, 8, 45, 6, 18], 'WILSON': [6, 8, 30, 0, 24], 'MOORE': [6, 8, 35, 0, 24],
    'TAYLOR'  : [6, 8, 40, 0, 24], 'ANDERSON': [2, 3, 60, 0, 6], 'THOMAS': [2, 4, 40, 0, 24],
    'JACKSON' : [2, 4, 60, 8, 16], 'WHITE': [2, 6, 55, 0, 24], 'HARRIS': [2, 6, 45, 0, 24],
    'MARTIN'  : [2, 3, 40, 0, 24], 'THOMPSON': [2, 5, 50, 12, 24], 'GARCIA': [2, 4, 50, 0, 24],
    'MARTINEZ': [2, 4, 40, 0, 24], 'ROBINSON': [2, 5, 50, 0, 24]})
REQUIRED = [1, 1, 2, 3, 6, 6, 7, 8, 9, 8, 8, 8, 7, 6, 6, 5, 5, 4, 4, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2]
MODEL = gurobipy.Model("Work Schedule")

# Create variable
x = MODEL.addVars(EMPLOYEE, range(24), range(1, 25), vtype=gurobipy.GRB.BINARY)

MODEL.update()

# Obj
MODEL.setObjective(gurobipy.quicksum((j - i) * x[d, i, j] * COST[d] for d in EMPLOYEE for i in range(24) for j in range(i + 1, 25)), sense=gurobipy.GRB.MINIMIZE)

# Constraints
MODEL.addConstrs(x.sum(d) <= (gurobipy.quicksum(x[d, i, j] for i in range(START[d], END[d] + 1) for j in range(i + 1, END[d] + 1) if MIN[d] <= j - i <= MAX[d])) for d in EMPLOYEE)
MODEL.addConstrs(gurobipy.quicksum(x[d, i, j] for i in range(START[d], END[d] + 1) for j in range(i + 1,END[d] + 1) if MIN[d] <= j - i <= MAX[d]) <= 1 for d in EMPLOYEE)
MODEL.addConstrs(gurobipy.quicksum(x[d, i, j] for d in EMPLOYEE for i in range(24) for j in range(i + 1, 25) if i <= c < j) >= REQUIRED[c] for c in range(24))

# Excute
MODEL.optimize()
```

My pulp Code:

```
# Create Data
# EMPLOYEE: 0)MIN, 1)MAX, 2)COST, 3)START, 4)END
md = {'SMITH':[6,8,30,6,20],'JOHNSON':[6,8,50,0,24],'WILLIAMS':[6,8,30,0,24],
    'JONES':[6,8,30,0,24],'BROWN':[6,8,40,0,24],'DAVIS':[6,8,50,0,24],
    'MILLER':[6,8,45,6,18],'WILSON':[6,8,30,0,24],'MOORE':[6,8,35,0,24],
    'TAYLOR':[6,8,40,0,24],'ANDERSON':[2,3,60,0,6],'THOMAS':[2,4,40,0,24],
    'JACKSON':[2,4,60,8,16],'WHITE':[2,6,55,0,24],'HARRIS':[2,6,45,0,24],
    'MARTIN':[2,3,40,0,24],'THOMPSON':[2,5,50,12,24],'GARCIA':[2,4,50,0,24],
    'MARTINEZ':[2,4,40,0,24],'ROBINSON':[2,5,50,0,24]}

REQUIRED = [1, 1, 2, 3, 6, 6, 7, 8, 9, 8, 8, 8, 7, 6, 6, 5, 5, 4, 4, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2]
MIN, MAX, COST, START, END = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4
t = 24

# Create Op
MODEL = pulp.LpProblem("Work Schedule", pulp.LpMinimize)

# Create variable
x = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("x", [(d, i, j) for d in md.keys() for i in range(t) for j in range(1, t+1)], cat=pulp.LpBinary)

# Create Obj
MODEL += pulp.lpSum((j - i) * x[d, i, j] * md[d][COST] for i in range(t) for j in range(i+1, t+1) for d in md.keys())

# Constraints
for c in range(len(REQUIRED)):
    MODEL += pulp.lpSum(x[d, i, j] for d in md.keys() for i in range(t) for j in range(i+1, t+1) if i <= c < j) >= REQUIRED[c]
for k, v in md.items():
    #print(k, v)
    MODEL += pulp.lpSum(x[k, i, j] for i in range(v[START], v[END] + 1) for j in range(i + 1, v[END] + 1) if v[MIN] <= (j - i) <= v[MAX]) <= 1
    MODEL += pulp.lpSum(x[k, i, j] for i in range(v[START], v[END] + 1) for j in range(i + 1, t + 1)) <= pulp.lpSum(x[k, i, j] for i in range(v[START], v[END] + 1) for j in range(i + 1, v[END] + 1) if v[MIN] <= (j - i) <= v[MAX])
MODEL.solve()
```

The gurobipy code result is:
[image]

My pulp code result is:
[image]

Obviously, my result is incorrect, but when I went through each condition individually, I couldn't find any differences. Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks a lot, everyone.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I don't understand `for j in range(i + 1, 25)`. `i` is already an index over hours. Why are you then adding a third dimension from the beginning of the day up to the current hour?

Comment: Thank you reply me and my understanding is j will not less than i, like i=0, j=9 is ok, but i=9, j=0 is false

Comment: That's what it does; but why does it do that?

Comment: Cause i is start time and j is end time, (j-i) is the duration or total cost hours, if j=0, i=9, i-j=-9 which affect the obj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't trust your results for either of the methods, because you've omitted `ANDERSON`'s first shift half. (See original code's reference to cyclics and `GALLERY`).

I still don't think that you should have what amounts to O(n^2) variables. It's easy enough to constrain the employee-hour selection variables to be contiguous without that extra dimension.

```py
import pulp
import pandas as pd


md = pd.DataFrame(
    columns=('EmployeeName', 'MinHours', 'MaxHours', 'HourlyWage', 'Start', 'End'),
    data=[
        (   'SMITH', 6, 8, 30,  6, 20),
        ( 'JOHNSON', 6, 8, 50,  0, 24),
        ('WILLIAMS', 6, 8, 30,  0, 24),
        (   'JONES', 6, 8, 30,  0, 24),
        (   'BROWN', 6, 8, 40,  0, 24),
        (   'DAVIS', 6, 8, 50,  0, 24),
        (  'MILLER', 6, 8, 45,  6, 18),
        (  'WILSON', 6, 8, 30,  0, 24),
        (   'MOORE', 6, 8, 35,  0, 24),
        (  'TAYLOR', 6, 8, 40,  0, 24),
        ('ANDERSON', 2, 3, 60, 18, 24 + 6),
        (  'THOMAS', 2, 4, 40,  0, 24),
        ( 'JACKSON', 2, 4, 60,  8, 16),
        (   'WHITE', 2, 6, 55,  0, 24),
        (  'HARRIS', 2, 6, 45,  0, 24),
        (  'MARTIN', 2, 3, 40,  0, 24),
        ('THOMPSON', 2, 5, 50, 12, 24),
        (  'GARCIA', 2, 4, 50,  0, 24),
        ('MARTINEZ', 2, 4, 40,  0, 24),
        ('ROBINSON', 2, 5, 50,  0, 24),
    ],
).set_index(keys='EmployeeName', drop=True).sort_index()

# Hourly staffing requirements, over 24 hours only
hour48 = pd.RangeIndex(name='Hour', start=0, stop=48)
required = pd.Series(
    name='Required', index=hour48[:24],
    data=(1, 1, 2, 3, 6, 6, 7, 8, 9, 8, 8, 8, 7, 6, 6, 5, 5, 4, 4, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2),
)

# Long-style employee-hour selection variables, multi-indexed by employee and hour
flat = pd.DataFrame(
    data=pulp.LpVariable.matrix(name='sel', indices=(md.index, hour48), cat=pulp.LpBinary),
    index=md.index, columns=hour48,
).stack()
flat.name = 'Select'

# For each employee and available hour, each selection variable beside the employee data
lp_vars = pd.merge(
    left=md, right=flat, on='EmployeeName',
).set_index(flat.index)
hour_idx = lp_vars.index.get_level_values('Hour')
lp_vars = lp_vars[
    (hour_idx >= lp_vars['Start']) &
    (hour_idx < lp_vars['End'])
]

# The expense for each employee, as affine expressions
md['Duration'] = lp_vars['Select'].groupby('EmployeeName').agg(pulp.lpSum)
md['Expense'] = md['HourlyWage'] * md['Duration']

model = pulp.LpProblem(name='Work_Schedule', sense=pulp.LpMinimize)
model.setObjective(pulp.lpSum(md['Expense']))

for name, row in md.iterrows():
    model.addConstraint(
        name=f'hours_min_{name}',
        constraint=row['Duration'] >= row['MinHours'],
    )
    model.addConstraint(
        name=f'hours_max_{name}',
        constraint=row['Duration'] <= row['MaxHours'],
    )

hour_idx = lp_vars.index.get_level_values('Hour')
for hour, min_staff in required.items():
    hour_vars = lp_vars[hour_idx % 24 == hour]

    # For each hour (or the same hour in the next day), enforce minimum staff
    model.addConstraint(
        name=f'min_staff_{hour}',
        constraint=pulp.lpSum(hour_vars['Select']) >= min_staff,
    )

for name, selects in lp_vars['Select'].groupby('EmployeeName'):
    selects = selects.droplevel('EmployeeName')

    # At the beginning and end of the day, within the minimum number of working hours, the
    # selector values are simply monotonic
    employee = md.loc[name]
    nmin = employee['MinHours']
    for s0, s1 in zip(selects[:nmin-1], selects[1: nmin]):
        model.addConstraint(s0 <= s1)
    for s0, s1 in zip(selects[-nmin: -1], selects[1-nmin:]):
        model.addConstraint(s0 >= s1)

    # In the middle of the day, conditionally enforce monotonicity based on selection
    M = 48
    for i in range(nmin-1, selects.size-nmin):
        model.addConstraint(
            name=f'm_{name}_{selects.index[i]}',
            constraint=M*selects.iloc[i] <=
                       M*(selects.iloc[i+1] + 1) -
                       pulp.lpSum(selects.iloc[i+2: 1-nmin]),
        )

print(model)
model.solve()
if model.status != pulp.LpStatusOptimal:
    raise ValueError(model.status)

md[['Duration', 'Expense']] = md[['Duration', 'Expense']].map(pulp.LpAffineExpression.value)
lp_vars['Select'] = lp_vars['Select'].map(pulp.LpVariable.value)

pd.options.display.width = 200
pd.options.display.max_columns = 99
print(md)

hours_total = lp_vars['Select'].groupby('Hour').sum()
next_day = hours_total[required.size:]
hours_total[:next_day.size] += next_day.values
print(pd.DataFrame({
    'required': required,
    'allocated': hours_total[:required.size],
}))
print(
    lp_vars['Select']
    .astype(int)
    .unstack('Hour', fill_value=0)
    .sort_index(axis=1)
)
```

```
Work_Schedule:
MINIMIZE
60*sel_ANDERSON_18 + 60*sel_ANDERSON_19 + ...
SUBJECT TO
hours_min_ANDERSON: sel_ANDERSON_18 + sel_ANDERSON_19 + sel_ANDERSON_20
 + sel_ANDERSON_21 + sel_ANDERSON_22 + sel_ANDERSON_23 + sel_ANDERSON_24
 + sel_ANDERSON_25 + sel_ANDERSON_26 + sel_ANDERSON_27 + sel_ANDERSON_28
 + sel_ANDERSON_29 >= 2
...

VARIABLES
0 <= sel_ANDERSON_18 <= 1 Integer
0 <= sel_ANDERSON_19 <= 1 Integer
0 <= sel_ANDERSON_20 <= 1 Integer
...

Welcome to the CBC MILP Solver 
Version: 2.10.3 
Build Date: Dec 15 2019 

At line 2 NAME          MODEL
At line 3 ROWS
At line 467 COLUMNS
At line 5951 RHS
At line 6414 BOUNDS
At line 6833 ENDATA
Problem MODEL has 462 rows, 418 columns and 4229 elements
Coin0008I MODEL read with 0 errors
Option for timeMode changed from cpu to elapsed
Continuous objective value is 4700 - 0.01 seconds
...

Result - Optimal solution found

Objective value:                4700.00000000
...

              MinHours  MaxHours  HourlyWage  Start  End  Duration  Expense
EmployeeName                                                               
ANDERSON             2         3          60     18   30       2.0    120.0
BROWN                6         8          40      0   24       8.0    320.0
DAVIS                6         8          50      0   24       8.0    400.0
GARCIA               2         4          50      0   24       4.0    200.0
HARRIS               2         6          45      0   24       6.0    270.0
JACKSON              2         4          60      8   16       2.0    120.0
JOHNSON              6         8          50      0   24       8.0    400.0
JONES                6         8          30      0   24       8.0    240.0
MARTIN               2         3          40      0   24       3.0    120.0
MARTINEZ             2         4          40      0   24       4.0    160.0
MILLER               6         8          45      6   18       8.0    360.0
MOORE                6         8          35      0   24       8.0    280.0
ROBINSON             2         5          50      0   24       3.0    150.0
SMITH                6         8          30      6   20       8.0    240.0
TAYLOR               6         8          40      0   24       8.0    320.0
THOMAS               2         4          40      0   24       4.0    160.0
THOMPSON             2         5          50     12   24       5.0    250.0
WHITE                2         6          55      0   24       2.0    110.0
WILLIAMS             6         8          30      0   24       8.0    240.0
WILSON               6         8          30      0   24       8.0    240.0
      required  allocated
Hour                     
0            1        1.0
1            1        1.0
2            2        2.0
3            3        3.0
4            6        6.0
5            6        6.0
6            7        7.0
7            8        8.0
8            9        9.0
9            8        8.0
10           8        8.0
11           8        8.0
12           7        7.0
13           6        6.0
14           6        6.0
15           5        5.0
16           5        5.0
17           4        4.0
18           4        4.0
19           3        3.0
20           2        2.0
21           2        2.0
22           2        2.0
23           2        2.0
Hour          0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29
EmployeeName                                                                                                                        
ANDERSON       0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0
BROWN          0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
DAVIS          0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
GARCIA         0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
HARRIS         0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
JACKSON        0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
JOHNSON        0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
JONES          0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
MARTIN         0   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
MARTINEZ       0   0   0   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
MILLER         0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
MOORE          0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
ROBINSON       0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
SMITH          0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
TAYLOR         0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
THOMAS         0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
THOMPSON       0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
WHITE          0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
WILLIAMS       0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
WILSON         0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Comment: 1. I don't trust your results for either of the methods...: Yes, you are right, the code miss ANDERSON's condition and I just trust the wrong code.
2. I still don't think that you should have what amounts to O(n^2) variables...: Thank you very much for pointing out the issues related to the variables. I am a beginner in operations research, and I ran the code you provided. The constraints are exactly the same. I really appreciate your thorough explanation and corrections.

Comment: The first time i asking question on Stack Overflow, I'm truly grateful for the detailed explanation provided by you. My sincere thanks to this platform and to you.